# Regex Length issue

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to build a regex where it accepts domain names with the following conditions:

1. Allows DNS names (only hyphens, periods and alphanumeric characters allowed) upto 255 characters.
2. Hyphens can only appear in between letters
3. Should start with a letter and end with a letter. It will have minimum 3 characters (letters and periods mandatory, hyphen is optional.)
4. The length of the label before a period should be 63

Possible Cases:

1. a.b.c
2. a-a.b

Cases that should not pass

1. a-.b
2. qwertqwertqwertqwertqwertqwertqwertqwertqwertqwertqwertqwertqwerhhg.v
3. aaaa
4. aaa-a

What I have built looks like this:

```
^(([a-zA-z0-9][A-Z0-9a-z-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9][.])+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

But this does not accept a.b.c

Comment: `A-z` is a typo, you need to use `A-Z`.

Comment: Try [`^(?=.{1,255}$)[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9a-z-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:[.][a-zA-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9a-z-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/C7dZWz/1/) or - in PHP PCRE/Ruby Onigmo/Oniguruma - [`^(?=.{1,255}$)([a-zA-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9a-z-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)(?:[.]\g<1>)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/cnoicU/3)

Comment: Should be accepting any number of characters after a period. Fails when I add more than 63 chars after the dot. Can you please update @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Any number of characters after the period are acceptable

Comment: Then why did you say *The length of the label before a period should be 63*?

Comment: Yes, before a period it should be 63. And after a period it can be anything unless there's a period again

Comment: Not sure, really, but this - [`^(?=.{1,255}$)(?=[^.]{1,63}(?![^.]))[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(?:[.](?=[^.]{1,63}(?![^.]))[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)*(?:[.][^.]*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/C7dZWz/2) - might be what you need.

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: No, it also accepts "aa" which is invalid

Comment: Ok, and if you replace `*` with `+`? See https://regex101.com/r/C7dZWz/3

Comment: Still takes only 63 characters after the last period

Comment: Also can we not have hyphens at the end?

Comment: Probably, you want https://regex101.com/r/C7dZWz/5. Note it already allowed any number of chars after last `.`

Comment: Thankyou so much for your time. Can you please take few minutes to explain the whole pattern?

Comment: See the explanation below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{1,255}$)(?=[^.]{1,63}(?![^.]))[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(?:[.](?=[^.]{1,63}(?![^.]))[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)+(?:[.][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/C7dZWz/5).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{1,255}$)` - the whole string should have 1 to 255 chars
- `(?=[^.]{1,63}(?![^.]))` - there must be 1 to 63 chars other than `.` before the char other than `.` or end of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `)*` - zero or more repetitions
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group...

  - `[.]` - a dot
  - `(?=[^.]{1,63}(?![^.]))` - there must be 1 to 63 chars other than `.` before the char other than `.` or end of string
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
  - `(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a `-` followed with 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `)+` -... 1 or more times
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group...

  - `[.]` - a dot
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9-]*` - 1+ alphanumeric or `-` chars
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alphanumeric char (no hyphens at the end)
- `)?` -... 1 or 0 times (it is optional)
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
/^(?=[A-Z])((?:[A-Z\d]|(?<=[A-Z])-(?=[A-Z])){1,63})(?<=[A-Z])(?:\.[A-Z\d]+){1,2}$/im
```

Details:

- `^` - Start of the string.
- `(?=[A-Z])` - Positive lookahead: The whole string must start with a letter.
- `(` - A capturing group - the domain name.

  - `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group, needed due to the following quantifier.
  - `[A-Z\d]` - The first alternative: Either a letter or a digit.
  - `|` - Or.
  - `(?<=[A-Z])-(?=[A-Z])` - The second alternative: A hyphen, preceded with a letter
    and followed with a letter.
  - `)` - End of the non-capturing group.
  - `{1,63}` - This group (either alternative) must occur up to 63 times.
- `)` - End of the capturing group.
- `(?<=[A-Z])` - Positive lookbehid: The capturing group just matched (domain name)
  must end with a letter.
- `(?:` - A non-capturing group, also needed due to the following quantifier.

  - `\.[A-Z\d]+` - A dot and a sequence of letters or digits.
- `)` - End of the non-capturing group.
- `{1,2}` - This group must occur 1 or 2 times.
- `$` - End of the string.

You should definitely use `i` (case insensitive) option and if you check
a number of strings, each in a separate row, also `m` (multiline) option.

I didn't include any test for the whole length, but you didn't include it either.
I think, the main task here was to show how to match the case your regex failed.